# Show that every element in $k[X,Y]/{(XY)}$ has a unique expression of the form $a+Xf(X) + Yg(Y)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, commutative-algebra

> Show that every element in $k[X,Y]/{(XY)}$ has a unique expression of the form $a+Xf(X) + Yg(Y)$, where $a\in k,\ f\in k[X]$ and $g\in k[Y]$.

So I think that in $A = k[X,Y]/{(XY)}$, every power of the form $X^iY^j$ equals $0$ and then I could just eliminate those terms, so an element $h\in A$ would be of the form 
$$h = a_0 + f_1(X) + g_1(Y)$$
where we let $f_1(X) = a_1 + a_2X + \dots +a_{s+1}X^s$ and $g_1(X) = b_1 + b_2Y + \dots + b_{t+1}Y^t$. So letting $a = a_0 + a_1 + b_1$ and $f(X) = a_2 + a_3X + \dots + a_{s+1}X^{s-1}$ and $g(Y) = b_2 + b_2Y + \dots + b_{t+1}Y^{t-1}$, then
$$h = a + Xf(X) + Yg(Y)$$

For the uniqueness part, suppose we have $a_1, a_2, f_1, f_2, g_1, g_2$ such that
$$h = a_1 +Xf_1(X) + Yg_1(Y) = a_2 + Xf_2(X) + Yg_2(Y)$$
then 
$$X\left[f_1(X) - f_2(X)  \right] + Y\left[ g_1(Y)-g_2(Y)   \right] = a_1 - a_2$$
and since the left hand side has degree at least $1$ because of the terms on $X$ and $Y$, and the right hand side has degree $0$, it must be the case where we have 
$$f_1(X) - f_2(X) = 0,\; g_1(Y) - g_2(Y)=0$$
that is, 
$$f_1(X) = f_2(X),\; g_1(Y) = g_2(Y)$$
and then, also $a_1 = a_2$.

Is this proof correct? Thank you.

Comment: Why is this form unique?

Comment: This is perfectly ok !

Comment: @N.H. Thank you very much! :D

Comment: Sure, you're welcome !